# activate and deactivate in the same button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make this button to do two things, I want it to be green and says "activate" and when I press it the button turns red and says "deactivate" and changes a column in the data to 1, and vice versa .
and if the column in the database is 1 it needs to be red and if it is 0 it needs to be green .

if someone just can tell what's the term so I can look for it because I searched a lot and I didn't come across what I need .

Comment: could you provide a basic markup and the attempts tried?

Comment: are you looking for the word "toggle"?

Comment: @yiffyiffyiff does the toggle button do the same thing i described

Comment: The other term you're looking for is "pseudo element", particularly the [`::before` or  `::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and `classList.toggle`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("toggleBtn")) {
    return toggleBtn(evt.target);
  }
}

function toggleBtn(btn) {
  btn.classList.toggle("red");
  /** ... more actions **/
}
```

```css
.toggleBtn {
  background-color: #B8F4B8;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.toggleBtn:before {
  content: "Activate";
}

.toggleBtn.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.toggleBtn.red:before {
  content: "Deactivate";
}
```

```html
<button class="toggleBtn"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by @yiffyiffyiff, the term you are looking for is called toggling. It sounds like you want to toggle the state of the button from active to deactive and vice-versa.